# Как задать значения полей по умолчанию в модели eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть ли возможность прямо внутри модели App\Post задать значения по умолчанию, например для поля user_id типа:

```
'user_id'=>auth()->user()->id;
```

чтобы при создании записи в таблицу автоматически заносилось id текущего пользователя и это не нужно было бы указывать в методе create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть событие модели ['creating'](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events), в котором ты можешь задать нужную логику, например

```
// пример с добавлением слушателя события в методе boot модели
// есть и другие способы слушания событий модели, подробнее в документации
class Post extends Model{
    public static function boot(){
        parent::boot();
        static::creating(function(Post $post){
            if(empty($post->user_id)){
                $post->user_id = auth()->id();
            }
        });
    }
}
```